# Upload changes on ctrl + s in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm, remote-server

How can I upload changes of file from local to remote server when I saved it?

I want do it automatically when I pressed <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>s</kbd> shortcut, not manually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Go to `Tools | Deployment | Options...` and make the settings as shown [image: in this picture].

> Upload changed files automatically to the default server: **On explicit save Action (CTRL + S)**

**Update:**
In new version of PhpStorm, Go to `Tools | Deployment` and check `Automatic Upload`.